# form submit hook handler not getting called in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have `Drupal 7` site. It has custom module named say `myproducts`. This module has following hook

```
function myproducts_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

if(isset($form_id) && $form_id=='product_node_form')
{
   $form['#submit'][] = 'myform_form_submit';
}

}


function myform_form_submit(){
 echo 'test submit handler'; exit();
 }
```

#### But `myform_form_submit` is not getting called.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code works. To be sure it doesn't contain any small invisible to human eye error, I repeated it on my dev site. So, possibly the issue is not here. Maybe you didn't clear the cache, or your node type is not called "product", or something similar...

Comment: Also make sure your module is enabled. Instead of using `echo(); exit();` you should use `drupal_set_message('test submit handler');` to make sure you do not interrupt normal Drupal execution. One last thing, you forgot to pass the arguments to `myform_form_submit()` it should be `myform_form_submit($form, &$form_state)`. I don't think that's what blocking your code but, you know, best practice and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors. Make sure you clear your cache using Drush(`drush cc all`) or through [Drupal's UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/337176). After that I would echo `$form_id` to make see what's the actual value of it is. I would also recommend using the [devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel). It's great for debugging!